# Using data table to run 100,000 Fisher's Exact Tests is slower than apply

Tags: r, performance, optimization, time

Good morning,

I'm trying to use R to run 100,000 Fisher's exact tests on simulated genetic data very quickly, preferably in under 30 seconds (since I need to permute case-control labels and iterate the process 1,000 times, so it runs overnight).

I tried using data tables on melted, tidy data, which contains about 200,000,000 rows and four columns (subject ID, disease status, position and 'value' [the number of wild-type alleles, a 3-factor variable]). The function groups by position, then performs Fisher exact tests on value against disease.

```
> head(casecontrol3)
   ident disease position value
1:     1       0    36044     2
2:     2       0    36044     2
3:     3       0    36044     1
4:     4       0    36044     1
5:     5       0    36044     2
6:     6       0    36044     1

> setkey(casecontrol3,position)
> system.time(casecontrol4  <- casecontrol3[,list(p=fisher.test(value,
+     factor(disease))$p.value), by=position])
   user  system elapsed 
215.430  11.878 229.148

> head(casecontrol4)
   position            p
1:    36044 6.263228e-40
2:    36495 1.155289e-68
3:    38411 7.842216e-19
4:    41083 1.272841e-69
5:    41866 2.264452e-09
6:    41894 9.833324e-10
```

However, it's really slow in comparison to using a simple apply function on flattened, messy, case-control tables (100,000 rows; the columns contain info re: disease status and number of wild-type alleles, so the apply function first converts each row into a 2x3 case-control tables, and uses the matrix syntax of Fisher's exact test). It takes about 20 seconds of running time to convert the data from a previous (unmelted) form into this form (not shown).

```
> head(cctab)
     control_aa control_aA control_AA case_aa case_aA case_AA
[1,]        291        501        208     521     432      47
[2,]        213        518        269      23     392     585
[3,]        170        499        331     215     628     157
[4,]        657        308         35     269     619     112
[5,]        439        463         98     348     597      55
[6,]        410        480        110     323     616      61

> myfisher <- function(row){
+     contab <- matrix(as.integer(row),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
+     pval <- fisher.test(contab)$p.value
+     return(pval)
+ }

> system.time(tab <- apply(cctab,1,"myfisher"))
   user  system elapsed 
 28.846  10.989  40.173

> head(tab)
[1] 6.263228e-40 1.155289e-68 7.842216e-19 1.272841e-69 2.264452e-09 9.833324e-10
```

As you can see, using apply is much faster than data.table, which *really* surprises me. And the results are exactly the same:

```
> identical(casecontrol4$p,tab)
[1] TRUE
```

Does anyone who is an expert at using data.table know how I could speed up my code with it? Or is the data just too big for me to use it in the melted form (which rules out using data.table, dplyr, etc)? Note that I haven't tried dplyr, as I've heard that data.table is faster for big data sets like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Aside from the speed issue, I would be speaking to a statistician to sort out whether running 100K tests is appropriate without some form of correction. It sets off all sorts of alarm bells for me.

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact problem, but what I do in R is use the R profiler. It extracts a number of stack samples, which I then look at manually in a text editor. You don't need to look at a lot of samples. If it's spending a good fraction of it's time, like 50%, doing something that could be avoided, then that fraction of samples will show it.

Comment: @thelatemail: multiple testing correction will be done later (e.g. Bonferroni).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: I tried using R profiler for both the apply method and the data.table method. Neither method has a significant bottleneck, apart from using fisher.test itself.

Comment: @AJP123: OK, so you're saying almost all stack samples contained fisher.test? Then what I would do is see if I need everything fisher.test is doing for me. It probably errs on the side of generality - doing more than I need. Then I would see if there's a way to make it do just the minimum. Finally, if that's not enough, I would consider dipping into a compiled language. Everybody wants R to be fast, but it's main purpose is not to be fast, but to be easy to use.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Yeah - most stack samples contained fisher.test. I'll chat to my supervisor about it, and if we need it to go faster, we'll probably have a look at using Rcpp.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest another route -- adding an HPC element to your approach.

You can use mutliple CPU or GPU cores, scale up a free cluster of computers on AWS EC2, connect to AWS EMR, or use any of a plethora of great HPC tools to faciliate your existing code.

Check our the [CRAN HPC Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) and this [tutorial](http://hack-r.com/quick-tip-how-to-use-segue-connect-r-with-emr-easily-in-6-short-steps/).