# Fisher exact test takes long in R, how the improve speed?

Tags: r, performance, statistics, chi-squared

My table has 770,000 rows and 
what I did is:

```
mydata <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "select * from table")    
mydata$pvalue <- apply(as.matrix(mydata[, c(3,5,4,6)]), 1, function(x) fisher.test(matrix(x, nrow=2))$p.value)
```

to get pvalues.

But it takes so long. (It has been over 24hours and it is still running).
Should I use other way to speed up Fisher exact in R?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161801/using-data-table-to-run-100-000-fishers-exact-tests-is-slower-than-apply Furthermore, can you tell something about the maximum values in the matrix?

Comment: 568,650,570 is the maximum value (column 6)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Fisher exact test` is like `chi-squared test`.

From wikipedia:

> With large samples, a chi-squared test can be used in this situation.
>   However, the significance value it provides is only an approximation,
>   because the sampling distribution of the test statistic that is
>   calculated is only approximately equal to the theoretical chi-squared
>   distribution.

Comment: I know the fisher exact test is like chi-squared test. but I need to use Fisher exact test for my table. My question is: is there any other way (different code? or different software?) 
Thank you